# handling data while replacing delimiter from double quotes

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I'm trying to remove the pipe delimiter from double quotes,its replacing with following code but its not handling empty filed and numeric fields. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
 sed 's/|*\([^"]\)/\1/g;s/\([^"]\),*/\1/g' test.csv
```

INPUT:

```
"Southern|Palms"|"AA|None"|"4"|"Kenya"|"MBA"|"Ken|Coast"|"Y"|1/11/2019 00:00:00|30/4/2020 00:00:00|"TH"||40.00|"HB|AI"||||||"Y"||||
```

OUTPUT:

```
"SouthernPalms"|"AANone"|"4"|"Kenya"|"MBA"|"KenCoast"|"Y"1/11/2019 00:00:0030/4/2020 00:00:00|"TH"40.00|"HBAI"|"Y"|
```

Expected Output:

```
"Southern Palms"|"AA None"|"4"|"Kenya"|"MBA"|"Ken Coast"|"Y"|1/11/2019 00:00:00|30/4/2020 00:00:00|"TH"||40.00|"HB AI"||||||"Y"||||
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^"|])\|($|[^"|])/\1 \2/g' <file>
```

Returns :

```
"Southern Palms"|"AA None"|"4"|"Kenya"|"MBA"|"Ken Coast"|"Y"|1/11/2019 00:00:00 30/4/2020 00:00:00|"TH"||40.00|"HB AI"||||||"Y"||||
```

It won't work for lines like this and I'm sure there are many other examples that could break the regexp :

```
"Southern|Palms"|"AA|||None"|"4"|"Kenya"|"MBA"|"Ken|Coast"|"Y"|1/11/2019 00:00:00|30/4/2020 00:00:00|"TH"||40.00|"HB|AI"||||||"Y"||||
```

But awk/sed are not the proper tools to read csv with quotechar and escapechar. For complex files like this, I would consider using python or any CSV reader that take these options into account.

Comment: how do we escape the quotes in between dates.                                               
 result : 1/11/2019 00:00:00 30/4/2020 00:00:00  expected : 1/11/2019 00:00:00 | 30/4/2020 00:00:00